# Offset on an array (Sprig)

Tags: craft4, plugin-sprig

I'm trying to create a load more function using a filtered set of entries, then passing those entries into the Load More component using Sprig.

I get the error "Impossible to invoke a method ("offset") on an array."

This is the code

**Template**

```
    {# If the user has selected "Auto" it'll auto populate below from section selected. #}
    {% if block.blockItemsManual|length %}
        {% set entries = block.blockItemsManual.entries.all() %}
    {% else %}
        {% set entries = craft.entries.section(block.blockItemsAuto).all() %}
    {% endif %}
    {# Show a Load More button that loads in more data via Sprig #}
    {{ sprig('_components/loadMore_grid', {'limit': 3, 'selectedEntries': entries }) }}
    {{ sprig.script }}
```

**Component**

```
{# Sets a default value if not defined by the `s-val:*` attribute on the button #}
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}

{% set entryQuery = selectedEntries.offset(offset).limit(limit) %}
{% set entries = entryQuery.all() %}


{% for entry in entries %}
......
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you call `.all()` on the element queries, `entries` represents an array and therefore you cannot call `.offset()` on it. Leaving out `.all()` would allow you to call other functions on the query, for example:

```
{% set entryQuery = craft.entries.section(block.blockItemsAuto) %}

{% set entries = entryQuery.offset(offset).limit(limit).all() %}
```

However, when using Sprig you should never pass objects (or arrays of objects) into a component, see https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/sprig#component-variables :

> Only primitive data types can be used as values: strings, numbers, booleans and arrays. Objects, models and elements cannot be used. If you want to pass an element (or set of elements) into a Sprig component then you should pass in an ID (or array of IDs) instead and then fetch the element from within the component.

So in this case I think you'd be better off either moving all of the logic into the component, or just passing an array of entry IDs into it.

Comment: I've used the array of entry IDs with success in a few instances. Can confirm it works great.